# How can i return an message but like an image or to scale it in Python? (for bar code generator-32)

Tags: python, barcode

i want to make an program to return an barcode using Code 39 but i want to make it without libarys. So here is my program and my only one question is, how can i return that a message like an image or to scale it to appear like an bar code?

```
from itertools import groupby
def bar_code_39_generator(message):
    final = []
    characters = {'0': '101001101101', '1': '110100101011', '2': '101100101011', '3': '110110010101',
                  '4': '101001101011', '5': '110100110101', '6': '101100110101', '7': '101001011011',
                  '8': '110100101101', '9': '101100101101', 'A': '110101001011', 'B': '101101001011',
                  'C': '110110100101', 'D': '101011001011', 'E': '110101100101', 'F': '101101100101',
                  'G': '101010011011', 'H': '110101001101', 'I': '101101001101', 'J': '101011001101',
                  'K': '110101010011', 'L': '101101010011', 'M': '110110101001', 'N': '101011010011',
                  'O': '110101101001', 'P': '101101101001', 'Q': '101010110011', 'R': '110101011001',
                  'S': '101101011001', 'T': '101011011001', 'U': '110010101011', 'V': '100110101011',
                  'W': '110011010101', 'X': '100101101011', 'Y': '110010110101', 'Z': '100110110101'}
    for string in list(message):
        group = [''.join(list(x)) for k, v in characters.items() for _, x in groupby(v) if k == string]
        final.append(''.join([[['▮', '|'][a != '11'], ' ' * len(a)][a not in ['11', '1']] for a in group]))
    return '| |▮▮| '+''.join(final)+' | |▮▮|'
```

For input:

```
'ABDA'
```

you recive:

```
'| |▮▮| ▮ | |  | ▮| ▮ |  | ▮| | ▮  | ▮▮ | |  | ▮ | |▮▮|'
```

Comment: without libraries ?  but you are using itertools ?

Comment: Sorry, i mean without barcode libary. I can use any other but not that one because it will be to easy